# Finding special charaters in a string

Tags: php, regex

**Problem:-**

I am using the following regular expression for searching the special characters in a string

```
/^((?!^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$).)*$/
```

But I do not know how to get all the special characters from the string.

Like `preg_match_all($pattern,'adcbasjkd*ACas!',$match)`

gives

```
array
(
    0 => 'adcbasjkd*ACas!'
    1 => '!'
)
```

As you can see I am not getting the `*` present in `adcbasjkd*ACas!` as the result.

**Question:-**

So how can I get all the characters that match the pattern ?

And is the pattern fine for finding the special characters as I am not so good with regex.

Comment: What are "special characters"? Do they bite or somehow behave special?

Comment: @arkascha may be to me !!

Comment: :-) I guess you mean "non-ascii characters". Or "non-7-bit characters". There is no distinction between "normal" and "special" characters. A character is a character. And they all do have character. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]
```

You can directly use this.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/26

```
$re = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]/mi";
$str = "adcbasjkd*ACas!";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

This regex says that capture all that  belongs to the character class available.Character class is negated so anything not inside it will be captured.
The global flag by default is on.So it will match all such characters.

Comment: If possible can you tell me what this regex is doing ?

Answer (score 2):

With a negated class

```
$pattern = '/[^a-z\d]/i';
preg_match_all($pattern,'adcbasjkd*ACas!',$match);
```

The regex `[^a-z\d]` with ignoreCase flag captures anything that's not alphabets and numbers.

Comment: This will consider the numbers too as the special characters. Isnt it ?

Comment: @Letmesee Okay. Now it will not consider numbers as special characters.

Comment: Can you explain the regex ?

Comment: @Letmesee `[^]` is a negated character class. a-z defines a range from a to z and \d is for digits. So, it's saying match anything other than numbers and alhpabets.

Comment: @Letmesee Let me see.. Okay! You're welcome. Glad to have helped :)